# B2C - pass parameter in url from .net5 application

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am calling a b2c custom policy from my .net5 application. The code I'm using to redirect users from the application to the custom policy screen is:

```
var scheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
var properties = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = redirectUrl };
properties.Items["policy"] = "B2C_1A_xxxxxx;

return Challenge(properties, scheme);
```

I also want to pass a value across from my application to pre-populate an input on the B2C screen.

I am able to get a value from a url parameter by using `OAUTH-KV:KeyValueKey` in the custom policy. Such that when I add `&KeyValueKey=KeyValueValue` to the url manually, I am able to display `KeyValueValue` in the relevant input.

However, am unable to update the C# code I have in the application so that I can generate the url with the parameter value included in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add this query parameter to your Open Id Connect middleware in the startup.
For example:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions()
{
    //.. 
    Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
        {
            context.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter("KeyValueKey", "KeyValueValue");

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
    //.. 
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this got me to where I needed. I ended up putting the code in ConfigureServices instead of Configure.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/enable-authentication-web-application-options#pass-a-custom-query-string-parameter